# CodeDeploy: Script at specified location: scripts/stop_server run as user root failed with exit code 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline

No matter what I put inside the `stop_server` file the CodeDeploy ends up with the error as above.
I even commented out all the lines to simplify debugging, so now it looks inside like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# pkill -f node
```

My `appspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /app.js
    destination: /home/ec2-user/node-website
  - source: /package.json
    destination: /home/ec2-user/node-website
  - source: /public/
    destination: /home/ec2-user/node-website/public
  - source: /node_modules
    destination: /home/ec2-user/node-website/node_modules

permissions:
  - object: /
      pattern: "**"
      owner: ec2-user
      group: ec2-user

hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies
      timeout: 300
      runas: ec2-user
    #- location: scripts/codestar_remote_access
    #  timeout: 300
    #  runas: ec2-user
    - location: scripts/start_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: ec2-user

  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: ec2-user
```

Any sugestions highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

When you do a deployment, it will actually use the ApplicationStop from your last successful deployment, not your current deployment. I resolved the problem by deleting the application that I have problem with and creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the code-deploy logs to find more details, the logs is normally located in:

```
/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log
```

Find more detailed error logs and let me know if you still cannot figure it out

Comment: i dont have this folder of logs why  still i have `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root`

Comment: @shareef you need to clean up everything inside that folder. use `sudo rm -r -f *` and restart the codedeploy-agent again.